# hydra 7.5 on windows 7

Tags: cygwin, windows-7-x64, hydra

I've installed Hydra 7.5 for windows 7 with Cygwin (include the Devel package) and i type the command ./hydra -h and this is the result, so i assume that everything works fine
[./hydra -h result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEWh1.jpg)

But when i'm trying to use it (it's the first time that i use tools like that) i take the following

`$ hydra -l admin -P rockyou.txt ftp://192.168.1.1
-bash: hydra: command not found`

This is an example of a command that i used, i typed also other commands with the same result...

I will appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that your batch is not in the rigth place, try dragging the hydra.exe to the cmd and running the command.